# How to fix spark.read.format("parquet") error

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, databricks-connect

I'm running Scala code on Azure databricks well. Now I want to move this code from Azure notebook to eclipse.

1. I install databricks connection following Microsoft document successfully. Pass databricks data connection test.
2. I also installed SBT and import to my project in eclipse
3. I create scala object in eclipse and also I import all jar files as external file in pyspark

---

```
package Student

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.util.Properties
//import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils

object Test {
  
  def isTypeSame(df: DataFrame, name: String, coltype: String) = (df.schema(name).dataType.toString == coltype)
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    var Result = true
    val Borrowers = List(("col1", "StringType"),("col2", "StringType"),("col3", "DecimalType(38,18)"))
    val dfPcllcus22 = spark.read.format("parquet").load("/mnt/slraw/ServiceCenter=*******.parquet")
    
    if (Result == false) println("Test Fail, Please check") else println("Test Pass")  
  }
}
```

---

When I run this code in eclipse, it shows cannot find main class. But if I comment "`val dfPcllcus22 = spark.read.format("parquet").load("/mnt/slraw/ServiceCenter=*******.parquet")`", pass the test.
So it seems spark.read.format cannot be recognized.

I'm new to Scala and DataBricks.
I was researching result for several days but still cannot solve it.
If anyone can help, really appreciate.
Environment is a bit complicated to me, if more information required, please let me know

Comment: could you share your complete build.sbt file and complete code ?? since your provided code does not have this line for spakSession creation `val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("SparkDBFSParquet")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
`

Comment: please provide the databricks version you are using so that i could understand the spark version to be used.

Comment: You are genius. I miss exactly that line for spakSession creation. When I run code on Azure Notebook, I don't need to specify this. Thanks a lot

Comment: sure, adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SparkSession is needed to run your code in eclipse, since your provided code does not have this line for SparkSession creation leads to an error,

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkDBFSParquet").master("local[*]".getOrCreate()
```

Please add this line and run the code and it should work.